# Choose outgoing trunk in custom context FreePBX

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I need to be able to choose some trunk based on result of some SQL query, while making outbound call, i spent many time google some answers, but i cant find any. I know i can use outbound routes in freepxb, but i need to be more specific in conditions that defines trunks choosing, so i need to do it directly from context. 
Im sorry for my english (it's quite bad), but i hope u guys would able to understand what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is intrested in, you ll need to override [macro-dialout-trunk] to do that.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail, for example *how* to implement this?

Comment: FreePBX makes it difficult to select a trunk within the dialplan.  The simplest way as MarcoZink has suggested is to copy the dial macro and copy it to extensions_custom.conf.  There you can reverse engineer the code, and add trunk selection based on some variable you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom trunk with a custom dial string:

```
Local/$OUTNUM$@query-out
```

Then you can create an outbound route to send the calls to that trunk. The $OUTNUM$ is the variable with the number dialed according to what the route sends to the trunk and will use the dialplan according to the context "query-out"

Then you can add the context "query-out" to your extensions_custom.conf file:

```
[query-out]
;--
Your dialplan for query and result processing
with corresponding Dial according to query result
--;
```

Hope I could help.